# How to install systemd-resolved on centos7 and use systemd-resolve

Tags: centos, systemd, dns, systemd-resolved

I installed systemd-resolved on centos 7.9 with `yum install systemd-resolved`. This worked, and I am able to run `systemctl start systemd-resolved.service`. But when I try to run `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches` shows

```
sudo: systemd-resolve: command not found
```

And sure enough there is no `systemd-resolve`

I checked yum packages and I see nothing for systemd-resolve. How can I run systemd-resolve commands on centos7? Is there a different package I need to install?

Comment: `systemd-resolve` in RHEL8, 9 is part of `systemd` package. But in RHEL/CentOs 7 I see it is not available.

Comment: Then why can I `yum install systemd-resolved`, what good is that service if I cant run the `systemd-resolve` binary?

Comment: Requests for learning materials (tutorials, how-tos etc.) are off topic, Dave.